# How to make Passport Google OAuth2.0 work with react-google-login?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-oauth, passport.js

My app was using Passport Google OAuth2.0, but I found out that I needed to get a response on the front-end to set the state of a custom hook that grants access to the private routes and that didn't seem possible with Passport, thus I came across this `react-google-login` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login), which allows me to define an `onSuccess` callback.

Now, is it possible to make this React package work with Passport Google OAuth strategy without conflicts? I want Passport to keep handling user creation on the database and generating JWT token. I just have no idea how to make them communicate with each other in such way that I can get to the `onSuccess` callback.

My Google Strategy and authentication routes are exactly like this:

**passport.js**

```
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: `${serverUrl}${process.env.GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL}`,
      },
      function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        User.findOrCreate(
          { googleId: profile.id },
          { first_name: profile.displayName, email: profile._json.email },
          function (err, user) {
            return cb(err, user);
          }
        );
      }
    )
  );
```

**auth.js**

```
router.get(
  "/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: ["email", "profile"],
  })
);

const clientUrl =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? process.env.CLIENT_URL_PROD
    : process.env.CLIENT_URL_DEV;

router.get(
  "/google/movie-log",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    failureRedirect: clientUrl + "/login",
    session: false,
  }),
  (req, res) => {
    const token = req.user.generateJWT();

    res.cookie("access_token", token, { httpOnly: true, sameSite: true });

    res.redirect(clientUrl + "/diary");
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

The React component:

**Login.js**

```
function handleSuccess(response) {
    authContext.setIsAuthenticated(true);
    navigate(state?.path || "/diary");
    console.log("Successfully authenticated");
}

function handleFailure(response) {
    console.log("Authentication failed");
}

<GoogleLogin
  clientId="my client ID"
  uxMode="redirect"
  scope="profile email"
  redirectUri="http://localhost:5000/auth/google/movie-log"
  onSuccess={handleSuccess}
  onFailure={handleFailure}
  cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
/>
```

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have any comments. I'm having the same problem... Can't access the response body from the callback route. What I do know is you're supposed to use either href or window.open with an onClick method which redirects to backend API route. The auth callback then redirects back to the frontend, but the response body is lost in transmission. Guess you're out of luck if generating JWTs in json instead of cookies.